# Datagrip | GSSAPI Initiate Failed when trying to connect to impala

Tags: jdbc, impala, datagrip, gssapi

I'm trying to connect to Impala using jdbc, and am receiving the following error:
Unable to connect to server: GSS Initiate Failed.

1. I did run Kinit before.
2. I'm running datagrip 2023.1.1, and it seems to work on datagrip 2021.2.1

Did anyone ever encounter this issue?

Running kinit.
Setting the krb5.conf in the jre directory.

Comment: We have had customers reporting issues starting from 2022.3.X versions. Till now, we couldn't confirm it and therefore, asking you to report your issue here

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

including your Impala version, and attach the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files

Comment: Could you elaborate and enable `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` in data source VM Options and attach produced logs in a new [DataGrip issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE)?

Comment: Also, it could depend on JAVA version and JDBC driver that runs remote process... Could you try to specify a previous VM home path and try to connect again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change VM home path for your data source

[image]

and add the latest *jna-platform* library to your JDBC

[image]